# Technical drawing for logo design, what is your workflow?

Tags: logo, technical-drawing

3D printing is trending and some of my clients are asking for logo design be done ready in 3D with CAD blueprints. Meaning when I do my regular 2D logo design, I have to make sure it can be re-created in a manner, not by export and importing the path of the logo mark from the design file, but by drawing on a blank blueprint with clear instructions/dimensions/constraints.

I find it hard to use Adobe Illustrator to create accurate logo design where I need drawings mathematically perfectly aligned e.g. in tangent to a curve or to mark a curve with curvature. Smart-guide and snapping in AI wont help me to find the tangent of a line against a circle or to lock multiple shapes with constraints.

I resolve by working my design on Fusion 360 or FreeCAD. I am fine with them but I am not sure if they are the right tools everyone else are using for the same tasks. Or, are there better alternative to create CAD drawing in logo design?

And a futher question here: is Affinity Designer better or worse than Adobe Illustrator in doing this?

Here are some famous logos that were done in technical drawings:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both Illustrator and Affinity Designer are capable vector art and design tools, and either can accomplish the ***design*** work of creating a logo or lettermark.

The technical drawing part *can also* be done in either of these, but is more commonly done ***after*** the design effort is completed, in either a **CADD** tool or a **3D DCC** tool, both because you can create the relevant 3D information more easily and because, absent plugins, the basic vector art / design apps don't handle scale and dimensioning in a CADD-like manner; FreeCAD, OnShape, DraftSight and even AutoCad can handle all these tasks with ease - but I wouldn't DESIGN my logo there - with my personal workflow, I'd design in Affinity Designer, and develop the 3D in my **3D DCC** Tool-of-choice ([**Modo**](https://www.foundry.com/products/modo)) or directly in OnShape.

I'd be most likely to dimension and annotate in my CADD tool-of-choice, and then save those files as `.dwg`, `.dxf`, `.stl`, `.obj`, `.fbx` as needed.

To be clear: the "logos" you're showing were designed as logos, in whatever art medium the designers chose; the images you have up there are of *signage technical drawings / construction documents* (of which I've personally produced a fair few, having worked in architecture) and are a wholly separate effort and field.

You may find this previous question to be of help, BTW:

[Why are precise measurements frequently included in brand identities?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/121045/why-are-precise-measurements-frequently-included-in-brand-identities/121062#121062)

Hope all of this helps.

Comment: thx for the reply. I too work my design on AI and then make exact measurements on CAD tools. However sometimes i have to revise the design based on more precise measurements and constraints i did in CAD tools, so there's a bit running back and forth, especially when some logos required drastic changes if it has to meet exact golden ratio. So what i usually do is that the design is first created in AI as concept, redraw and calibrated in CAD, and import back into AI as more precise paths. This sounds okay?

Comment: Sounds spot-on and very familiar... though TBH - once I move into serious constructability & efficiency efforts at the CDs level, I don't stick too hard to exact proportions - that's probably due to the manner in which architecture is practised here in the US - material unit-of-sale measures drive modularity of proportion very strongly - and not just in bricks - also gyp, sheathing and lumber - so once you're out of conceptual design and getting hard-nosed and practical about constructability & cost, perfection of proportion drops away pretty completely!